# In "living out", is there a link sound between the two words?

Tags: pronunciation

I just came across a listening practice and heard a sentence

> People spend their lives working for money, rather than *living out* their dreams.

It seems that the word 'living out' was pronounced like' 'livi-nout', because as far as I know, the *ng* sound can not be the start of a syllable.

What's going on?

Comment: *the ng sound can not be the start of a syllable* You mean like *Eng-lish*?

Comment: English is start with /i/

Comment: Seems like a classic instance of [ellision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision).  It often happens unintentionally when a speaker is speaking too quickly.  The speaker might not even have known s/he did it.

Comment: If the /g/ in living is ellided, then the lack of two consonant sounds at the end of the syllable tends to shift the sound to the next syllable. What was /cv.cvcc vc/ becomes /cv.cv cvc/  (v = vowel, c = consonant). This happens as a rule withing words, and can happen between words as well. Some dialects of English pronounce *living* as *livin'* - using an alveolar /n/ instead of a velar /ng/. In which case there is no problem using the /n/ sound as the onset to the next syllable. Also see [liaison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French))

Comment: @PhilSweet The general consensus (for whatever reason—I don’t see any good argument either way) is that /ŋ/ is a single phoneme in English. In that case, “living out” was never /cv.cvcc vc/, only /cv.cvc vc/. The change is from one phoneme to another, and the rebracketing to /cv.cv cvc/ should happen equally in both pronunciations. Which, incidentally, I’d say it does; or rather, doesn’t. Regardless of whether I say “living out” or “livin’ out”, the nasal firmly belongs to the second syllable, not the third. It’s too lenis to be an initial consonant.

Comment: Unless the speaker is speaking very slow and precisely, all spoken English exhibits subtle changes where two words are spoken in succession.  And I'm reasonably certain that other languages exhibit this same phenomenon.  There is really nothing of interest here, other than to note that certain juxtapositions may cause trouble for folks who are not fluent in the language.

Comment: If a native speaker were to do that, it would likely sound more like "liveen gout". The g would not be lost, but it might seem to transfer to the next syllable.  It would be similar to "Long Island" sounding like "lawn guyland".

Answer (score 1):

In ordinary speech, there would not be a pause or gap between "living" and "out." They would form a continuous sequence of sound. How you choose to split this sequence into syllables is more a matter of phonological theory than of phonetics. There is no consensus on how English syllabifies consonants that come between two vowels.

You may have heard /n/ rather than the "ng" sound; this is not related to syllabification. It's an example of "g-dropping," where the suffix "ing" is pronounced with /n/ rather than the "ng" sound. This can occur regardless of the following sound--it would also be possible in "living room."

Answer (score 0):

You can link those two words together. I'm not a native speaker, but I guess that's how native speakers would usually pronounce it.

I've also read somewhere that the NG sound /ŋ/ can't start a syllable, but I guess this is just an observation about English words, at least not applicable to words derived by adding *-ing* (e.g. sing /sɪŋ/ -> singing /sɪŋɪŋ/) or to this type of linking two words together.